# IS 5: Newly added service provider is hidden for other user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When my colegue add new service provider, It's not vissible for me in UI and vice versa.
We both have admin privilegs and both service providers work.
We have only one tenant.
How can we make all providers visible for all admins in providers list?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you and your friend are two different users (not tenant admins but have admin privilege) of the tenant. If that the case a user can't see another users service app.

To achieve this, what you can do is create the service app from tenant admin and give the role for that service provider for both users. So both users can access that service providers afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have admin privileges but was unable to see SAML service providers or previously created issuers. There is no link in the UI to get to the page that shows this information.

https://wso2:9443/carbon/sso-saml/manage_service_providers.jsp

I found this link on StackOverflow rather than the WSO2 documentation site. It lists SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-Ons and allows you to update them and delete them properly.

I found it when I went looking for why I couldn't create an issuer with the same name as an issuer I previously created when creating a Service Provider (and issuer) in one step, then deleting them both (or as it turned out WSO2 deletes the Service Provider but leaves the saml single sign-on and issuer, but deletes the links to it, so it is there and not there at the same time i.e. creating one says duplicate issue but trying to use it said not found).

Sorry getting a bit ranty, when using WSO2, I hope you like reading forums and banging your head against the wall :(

Using WSO2IS 5.3.0.